# Use flock to back up sqlite?

Tags: backup, sqlite

I want to back up an SQLite database file without making a local copy to avoid flash memory wear. I'd also like to avoid moving the partition to a snapshottable file system like LVM.

I figured I could just run `flock database.db rsync ...` but when I search online I cannot find this technique recommended anywhere, which is often a sign that it might not be a good idea.

Will this work or is there a better way?

Comment: This ought to work. I'm a little surprised that rsync doesn't seem to lock files it's copying, or have that as an option.